# Trying to figure out how this AWK script works

Tags: text-processing, awk

In my shop, we have a piece of AWK code
that someone wrote sometime ago but did not document,
so we have no idea how to interpret the code.

```
awk -F'~"' ' {gsub(/~/, " ", $3); print $1"~\""$2"~\""$3"~\""$4}' INFILE.dat > OUTFILE.dat
```

Scenario:

In a `~` delimited text file, we have 12 columns; example below.

Note that data which is character in nature is double-quoted,
like columns 3, 9 and 10.

```
1235678~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149512~"10"~9999.44~2004-07-22~2006-05-22~2006-07-22~2006-05-29~"2000~2001"~"N"~0.00~9999.63~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149556
                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The ninth column is `varchar(100)`
that can contain the `~` field delimiter.

The above awk code converts the `~` in column 9 to a space
via the `gsub()` part (I think).

Can anyone tell me exactly how this code works, please?

The input file is `INFILE.dat`. 
The output file is `OUTFILE.dat`.

As for expected output, the only thing that should change
is the data in the ninth column. 
The `~` between `"2000~2001"` should be replaced by a space. 
The output line would look like:

```
1235678~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149512~"10"~9999.44~2004-07-22~2006-05-22~2006-07-22~2006-05-29~"2000 2001"~"N"~0.00~9999.63~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149556
                                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I updated the original post with more info and what I want to know is can anyone tell me exactly how this code works please?

Answer (score 3):

Your existing code is unnecessarily complicated. fragile, and hard-coded to only work on the specific fields in your specific data, which is why it's harder to understand than it should be and should really just be discarded.

The idiomatic way to replace any number of characters or strings inside double quotes with any other character or string, using any awk is:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/~/," ",$i)} 1' file
1235678~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149512~"10"~9999.44~2004-07-22~2006-05-22~2006-07-22~2006-05-29~"2000 2001"~"N"~0.00~9999.63~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149556
```

That just splits the line into `"`-separated fields so every even-numbered field is one that's between quotes (`"a"~"b"` = 1) `null` 2) **`a`** 3) `~` 4) **`b`** 5) `null`) and so those even-numbered fields are the ones we manipulate.

If you're not sure what that (or your original script) does, just add some print statements to see what the values of the various variables being used are, after a glance at the man page.

Your data is essentially a subset of CSV but with `~` instead of `,` as the separator, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for how to process CSVs with awk in general.

If you're going to be using awk, you should learn a bit about it. Your original script and this new script use very basic components of the awk language, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins so you can learn the basics at least and have that reference handy if you need it for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

A *human* may consider your file to be `~` delimited, however your awk expression considers it to be delimited by the two-character sequence `~"`. Hence the example line that you give consists of *four* fields:

1. ```
   1235678~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149512
   ```
2. ```
   10"~9999.44~2004-07-22~2006-05-22~2006-07-22~2006-05-29
   ```
3. ```
   2000~2001"
   ```
4. ```
   N"~0.00~9999.63~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149556
   ```

Applying `gsub(/~/, " ", $3)` hence replaces the (single) `~` within `2000~2001"` with a space. The string `"~\""` replaces the original `FS`: the outer quotes are string syntax, and the inner quote needs a backslash to protect it. Personally, I would have avoided that using just `print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4` or, assuming the intent is to print *all* the fields, used

```
awk -F'~"' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {gsub(/~/, " ", $3)} 1'
```

However, this approach seems fragile - can you ensure that the 9th "real" field will exist in the 3rd `~"` delimited field? I'd suggest exploring solutions that recognize that delimiters may exist within quoted fields - as they may in CSV for example. One such tool is [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/), in which you could do<sup>1</sup>

```
$ mlr -N --csv --fs '~' put '$9 = gsub($9,"~"," ")' INFILE.dat 
1235678~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149512~10~9999.44~2004-07-22~2006-05-22~2006-07-22~2006-05-29~2000 2001~N~0.00~9999.63~2005-04-13-13.49.42.149556
```

---

1. newer versions of Miller have a [gssub](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.11.0/reference-dsl-builtin-functions/#gssub) (string replacement) function that would be preferable in this context

Comment: unfortunately, I have no control over what software is installed on our Linux boxes....  And I do appreciate the detailed explanation..  clears up some questions I had. As for your specific concern about the ~ appearing in places other than the ninth column., this cannot happen.  The ninth column is the only free format field where a ~ can appear.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant thank you I have incorporated your comment in the answer

Comment: @steeldriver  .. and then improved on it !

Comment: @Paul_Pedant well... slightly golfed it maybe ;)